# How to pass objects from Java to JavaScript using JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, servlets

A while back I was given the answer of using JSON to pass things from my application to JavaScript. What I don't understand is how I actually pass the object to JavaScript I see that you have to use a .json file.

And then what? I am able to convert my Java objects to JSON objects but it's passing that I can't get my head around. I am using JSP and Servlets to write my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file extension `.json` is not so relevant. It's just all about the HTTP [Content Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header. As long as it's `application/json`, the webbrowser knows perfectly what to do with it. In terms of JSP/Servlet you basically need to create a servlet class which listens on a certain `url-pattern`, processes the request parameters or pathinfo accordingly and writes a JSON string to the response in the `doGet()` method.

Here's a fictive example of a servlet which returns city option value/label pairs based on the selected value of a country dropdown, it uses [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert fullworthy Java objects to JSON in an oneliner:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String country = request.getParameter("country");
    Map<String, String> cities = cityDAO.find(country);
    String json = new Gson().toJson(cities);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

Map such a servlet on an `url-pattern` of `/cities` in `web.xml` (or if you want a bit more SEO friendly approach, map it on `/cities/*` and use `request.getPathInfo()` instead).

Finally, in the JS code which is executed during onchange of a country dropdown, you just let it fire an asynchronous (ajaxical) request on this servlet with the selected country as parameter (or pathinfo). I'll give a [jQuery](http://jquery.com) based example since it insanely eases firing ajax requests and traversing/manipulating HTML DOM (the "raw" JS code would otherwise have been up to 5 times as long).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#country').change(function() {
        var selectedCountry = $(this).val();
        var servletUrl = 'cities?country=' + selectedCountry;

        $.getJSON(servletUrl, function(options) {
            var city = $('#city');
            $('>option', city).remove(); // Clean old options first.
            if (options) {
                $.each(options, function(value, label) {
                    dropdown2.append($('<option/>').val(value).text(label));
                });
            } else {
                dropdown2.append($('<option/>').text("Please select country"));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the appropriate HTML example of the JSP:

```
<select id="country" name="country">
    <c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
        <option value="${country.key}">${country.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
<select id="city" name="city">
    <option>Please select country</option>
</select>
```

(assuming that `${countries}` is an `Map<String, String>` in application scope)

Hope this clears the one and other :)

#### See also:

- [Related questions with tags `[json]+[jsp]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json+jsp).
- [Related questions with tags `[json]+[servlets]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json+servlets).

Answer (score 1):

JSON is basically a Javascript object storage format.  So, it's native to Javascript.

### Loading a JSON File

You could load a JSON file when your webpage is loaded like this, just like any .js file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.json"></script>
</head>

—clipped—
```

It is also important to have a callback function, or a function that's called when the JSON has loaded.  For example, the contents of "myfile.json" should read:

```
anz([arbitrary JSON here]);
```

where `anz()` is defined somewhere as:

```
function anz(JSONdata) {
    //process data here
}
```

JSON can also be [dynamically loaded](http://objectmix.com/javascript/339758-dynamically-load-json.html), or loaded after the page has rendered/loaded.

### Getting Data From a JSON File

So, once you have a JSON file that is somehow loaded, and calls your callback function with the JSON data, you can read it — just like any other [Javascript Object](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm).

If this was passed to your callback function…

```
{"data":{"user_name":"Joe", "user_id":"97304239042", "user_rank":3}}
```

… To get the user's name:

```
function anz(JSONdata) {
    var userName = JSONdata.data.user_name;
    // userName returns "Joe"
}
```